# Jekyll 3.1.0 Generates HTML files instead of folders

Tags: html, jekyll

When I was using Jekyll 2.x, the folder structure within `_blog` was like this:

`/blog/post1/index.html`
`/blog/post2/index.html`

But since upgrading it's like this:

`/blog/post1.html`
`/blog/post2.html`

So although the `permalink` setting in `_config.yml` is `permalink: /blog/:title`, all the links I use are broken. What's going on? Is there a setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permalink config should be `permalink: /blog/:title/` with a trailing slash.

Comment: you mean trailing slash ?

Comment: well I just noticed that your answer has 
_trailing space_
and not 
_trailing slash_

Comment: Thank you. And yes you do have a typo, probably worth changing. But I understood :) thanks!

Comment: Haaa !! Yes `trailing slash` not `trailing space`. It took me two minutes to find the problem in this one sentence response. Facepalm.